# Neo4j server not starting in 120 seconds

Tags: import, neo4j, runtime-error, graph-databases

I am trying to run a Neo4j server on AWS but it is giving following error:

```
* Restarting Neo4j Graph Database neo4j
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [26079]... waiting for server to be ready.......... Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

Searching Google I found information suggesting to increase the maximum number of open files to 40000; I have tried that but unfortunately the result is same.

**Specs:**

- OS version: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Neo4j : 2.0.3 stable release

Also, I am doing a batch import from two CSV files via batch importer after stopping the server but when I restart the server after import, it does not start and produces the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the Advice @Stefan Armbruster

I Just figured it out.

At time of installation, neo4j asks you to "user by which neo4j will run" and i let it default "neo4j".

But the actual user must be defined as root.

Comment: seriously? you should not run a service as root unless it requires a privileged port.

Comment: it dose require privileged access to the system and hence i had to do it

Answer (score 6):

To increase the number of open files allowed, check out http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/linux-performance-guide.html#_setting_the_number_of_open_files.

If it's still not starting up check `data/log/console.log` or use `neo4j start-no-wait`.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above helps try this in case you are upgrading from older version and what to migrate your data.

1.Create a copy of the default database folder located in the data/ folder.

2.Copy all the files from the old database into this folder overwriting or replacing the original content.

3. Make sure to remove  white spaces or just rename it without spacing.
4. Edit the neo4j-server.properties  and set the newly created folder with the db file. (**org.neo4j.server.database.location** = data/folder-name)
5. Edit the neo4j.properties. uncomment the (#allow_store_upgrade=true) to **allow_store_upgrade=true**
6. Restart your server.